# Morphism of Sheaves Given Morphism of Sheaves on a Base

Tags: algebraic-geometry

This is from Vakil's FOAG: exercise 2.5 C, part b. I understand how objects in the extension sheaf from a sheaf on a base $\mathcal B$ of a topology are created, but I am having trouble understanding how to produce a morphism of sheaves given a morphism of sheaves on a base.

Assume we have topological space $X$. Supposing we have two sheaves on our base $\mathcal B$, say $F$ and $G$, and maps $F(B_i) \to G(B_i)$ for all $B_i \in \mathcal B$, these induce maps between any stalks $F_x \to G_x$ we like, and we know also for any $x \in X$, that $F_x \simeq F^{ext}_x$, where $F^{ext}$ is our extended sheaf (likewise for $G^{ext}$). After this, I do not know how to proceed, nor do I know if I needed all of that information.

Comment: Are you familiar with why it's enough to specify the values of a sheaf on a base? The same considerations should help you through this problem.

Comment: I am not. It intuitively makes sense to me. Cover $U$ with basic open sets. If you know where those go you should be able to glue them together somehow using compatibility. The problem is Vakil left that as an exercise as well.

Comment: I'd encourage you to write out what the sheaf property for the covering by basic opens says, and then if you haven't had an a-ha moment, double-check the definition of a base of open sets for a topology. (If you're still not quite seeing it, I'd be happy to give you some help after you write your attempt in your post.)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "sheaf property for the covering by basic opens." Do you mean the sheaf axioms for a sheaf on a base?

Comment: For a sheaf of abelian groups $\mathcal{F}$ and an open cover $U_i$ of $U$, there's an exact sequence $0\to \mathcal{F}(U)\to\prod_i \mathcal{F}(U_i) \to \prod_{i,j} \mathcal{F}(U_i\cap U_j)$. Sound familiar?

Comment: I have seen the first part of that sequence and shown its injectivity. I have not seen the second arrow of the sequence. In addition, we are working over sets here, not groups, which I failed to specify.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108623/discussion-between-johnny-apple-and-kreiser).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicated by the KReiser hint, you can do as follows:

We see the following diagram :

[image]

The first and second rows are exact , due to sheaf property, the second square commute do to compactible with restriction. and the universal property of the kernel gives the morphism we want.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my best attempt at an answer. Realize $\mathcal F^{ext}(U)$ instead as the limit of the $F(B_i)$ over all possible coverings of $U$ by basic open sets. This has by definition maps to each of the $F(B_i)$ commuting with known restriction morphisms between them. Since we have maps $F(B_i) \to G(B_i)$ for all $i$ with commuting squares (a condition imposed on our restriction functions initially), this gives us maps from $\varprojlim F(B_i)$ to each of the $G(B_i)$ which commute with restrictions. By the universal property of the limit applied to $\varprojlim G(B_i)$, there must be a unique map from $F^{ext}(U) = \varprojlim F(B_i) \to \varprojlim G(B_i) = G^{ext}(U)$ for all $U$, as desired. This creates a morphism of sheaves because it plays well with restrictions, again by the universal property of limits.